# jira plugin format issue

Tags: jira

Does anybody know which date format is to be used, trying to create a plugin that generates a report that can be exported to excel or pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this for the Timecharts plugin. Try something like this:

Date createdDate = new Date();
String created = ManagerFactory.getOutlookDateManager().getOutlookDate(applicationProperties.getDefaultLocale()).formateDateTimePicker(createdDate);

~Matt